# Google charts eliminate space

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Is it possible to eliminate the space between each two bars and then add space?

Look at my example:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Time of Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Motivation Level');

  data.addRows([
    ["6/4/2015", 10] ,
      ["13/4/2015", 10] ,
      ["7/4/2015", 20] ,
      ["14/4/2015", 10] ,
    ["8/4/2015", 10] ,
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
    document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following fiddle. In the code I added the `options` array and set the `bar` value to `99%`. That reduced the spacing (I believe) as you required.

```
var options = {
    bar: {
        groupWidth: "99%"
    },
};

chart.draw(data, options);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mikeyfreake/ppnengec/